# Here API: route deviation

Tags: here-api

I have a defined a route with 10 waypoints, and I have a vehicle that has to follow this route. For every hour, I have to check if the current position of the vehicle is within this predefined route. If the vehicle is X km from the radius of the route, it has a route deviation.

My question is if there is a way for me to inform the complete route with the 10 points + the current position of the vehicle and to return the distance that it is of that route. I would need to use a REST method for this.

Is there any method in HERE for this? For I have already searched and have not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to solve this problem

1. Geofencing Extension API - Define a geofence around your route if you want to allow a threshold of deviation from the defined route.
2. Custom Location Extension API - Searching along a route's isoline to see if your asset(eg: truck) is on the right direction.
   You can go through the examples provided in the site on these topics or you can also look at the examples provided in tcs.ext.here.com/examples.